# Netlogo how to repeat a procedure in go procedur

Tags: process, netlogo

This is my matching procedure and it runs in SETUP process. This procedure means that my agents-sellers and buyers meet each other. but I have add switch named "oneShot". and when "oneShot" will be true my "matching" has to run in Go process.
my code looks like that:

```
to matching     

  ask sellers [ move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]]

  ask buyers  [ move-to one-of patches with [not any? buyers-here]]

  ask buyers  [ if any? sellers-here     [set shape "face happy"]
                if not any? sellers-here [set shape "face sad"]
                if any? sellers-here [set size 0.5]]

  ask sellers [ if any? buyers-here      [set shape "face happy"]
                if not any? buyers-here  [set shape "face sad"]
                if any? buyers-here [set size 0.5]]    

  ask patches with [count turtles-here = 2]
                   [ask one-of turtles-here [fd 0.15 
                    ask one-of other turtles-here [face myself fd -0.15]]]


end
```

what should I add to here??

Comment: Please clarify.  If you call this in your `go` procedure then your buyers and sellers will move each time you call go.  If you want this to run more than one when you call `go`, you can use `repeat`.   Additionally, you did not learn from the answer to your previous question about how to use `ifelse`.  Please review that (and add a comment if you do not understand).

Comment: thank you for that comment, i did it but there was problems with the process, thats why thought it were better not to change it now and to change it at the end when the model will run :) to this question: i did mistake, it runs in setup process, i have to use switch button "oneShot" and when oneshot will be true it must run in go process, I will edit my question now

Comment: No problem is created by calling `matching` in both `setup` and `go`, and you can call it conditionally: `if oneShot [matching]`.

Comment: i did it and I became this error message for this code :

ask sellers [ move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]]
MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.
error while seller 19 running MOVE-TO
  called by procedure MATCHING
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'STEP'

Comment: It looks like you forgot to create any `sellers`.

Comment: I did, there are 100 sellers and 100 buyers

Comment: MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.
error while seller 63 running MOVE-TO
  called by procedure MATCHING
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'STEP'

Comment: this is the error message

Comment: Yes, but what *number* was printed in the command window (not in the error alert)?

Comment: there is number 100. what does it mean?

Comment: I have 100 sellers and 100 buyers, it states on the my task, tahts why

Comment: Sorry to have misled you: the problem is arising because you do not have any empty patches.  You have to decide what you want to do in this case.

Comment: may be i can remove agents who are alone? or?

Answer (score 1):

```
ask sellers [
  let candidate one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]
  ifelse (candidate != nobody) [
    move-to candidate
  ][
    die   ;;or whatever you want to do when there are no empty patches
  ] 
]
```